# Oracle utl_match special characters

Tags: oracle

I'd like to use Oracle's utl_match.edit_distance function. It supposed to compare two strings and return the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_Distance).

```
select utl_match.edit_distance('a','b') from dual
```

returns 1 as expected, but

```
select utl_match.edit_distance('á','b') from dual
```

returns 2. Obviously I'd like to get 1.

It seems to be, it does not work correctly for special characters. I'm using Oracle 10.2.0.4 and AL32UTF8 character set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to the character set.  If I run the same test in a 10.2.0.3 and 11.1.0.7 database using ISO8859P15 as the character set, I get a distance of 1 as well.  I'm guessing that Oracle is computing the distance in terms of bytes rather than characters in variable-width character sets.

You can work around the problem using the CONVERT function to convert to a fixed-width character set (AL16UTF16 or a local character set)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_char1 varchar2(1 char) := 'á';
  3    l_char2 varchar2(1 char) := 'b';
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line(
  6      'In AL32UTF8: ' ||
  7        utl_match.edit_distance( l_char1, l_char2 ) );
  8    dbms_output.put_line(
  9      'In WE8ISO8859P15: ' ||
 10        utl_match.edit_distance(
 11            CONVERT( l_char1, 'WE8ISO8859P15', 'AL32UTF8' ),
 12            CONVERT( l_char2, 'WE8ISO8859P15', 'AL32UTF8' ) ) );
 13    dbms_output.put_line(
 14      'In AL16UTF16: ' ||
 15        utl_match.edit_distance(
 16            CONVERT( l_char1, 'AL16UTF16', 'AL32UTF8' ),
 17            CONVERT( l_char2, 'AL16UTF16', 'AL32UTF8' ) ) );
 18* end;
SQL> /
In AL32UTF8: 2
In WE8ISO8859P15: 1
In AL16UTF16: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Quite strange, but comparing 'a' with 'bb' gives 2 in AL32UTF8, 2 in  WE8ISO8859P15, but 3 in AL16UTF16.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it appears to be wrong.  However, this package is undocumented by Oracle, so is perhaps unsupported at present.